# D3 Graph: I am trying to add label to the arrow created in d3 graph but it is not getting added

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I am fairly new to d3.js and I have created two arrows in the d3 graph and I am trying to add the text in the center of the arrows, but I am unable to see the labels getting added to the arrows.

My codepen link is below:

https://codepen.io/Navin_Kris/pen/mdXwVoY

The code is as follows

```js
const data = [ { x1: 50, y1: 50, x2: 200, y2: 50, label: 'Arrow 1', rotation: '0', arrowcolor: '#62b6ae'},
               { x1: 50, y1: 70, x2: 200, y2: 70, label: 'Arrow 2', rotation: '180', arrowcolor: '#e71c1d'}]

var svg = d3.select('svg');

for(let d of data){
  var line = svg.append("line")
             .attr("d", "line_path")
             .attr("x1",d.x1)  
             .attr("y1",d.y1)  
             .attr("x2",d.x2)  
             .attr("y2",d.y2)  
             .attr("stroke", d.arrowcolor)  
             .attr("stroke-width",2)  
             .attr("marker-end", markercolor(d.arrowcolor))
             .attr("rotate", d.rotation); 
  
  var value = d3.select('line');

  value.append("text")
    .attr("dy", 30)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(d.label);
}

function markercolor(color) {
  svg.append("svg:defs").append("svg:marker")
    .attr("id", color.toString().replace("#", ""))
    .attr("refX", 6)
    .attr("refY", 6)
    .attr("markerWidth", 30)
    .attr("markerHeight", 30)
    .attr("markerUnits","userSpaceOnUse")
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M 0 0 12 6 0 12 3 6")
    .style("fill", color);

  return "url(" + color + ")";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300" height="200">
</svg>
```

Could you please help me out on this.

Comment: you don't have an x and an y attributes for the text.

Comment: Fixed it now, I have added my fix as part of the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it , posting the fix for anyone who will have same issue:

```
for(let d of data){
  var line = svg.append("line")
             .attr("d", "line_path")
             .attr("x1",d.x1)  
             .attr("y1",d.y1)  
             .attr("x2",d.x2)  
             .attr("y2",d.y2)  
             .attr("stroke", d.arrowcolor)  
             .attr("stroke-width",2)  
             .attr("marker-end", markercolor(d.arrowcolor))
             .attr("rotate", d.rotation); 
  
  svg.append("text")
    .attr("dx", (d.x1 + d.x2)/2)
    .attr("dy", d.y1)
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(d.label);
}
```